# Open an executable file without an ".exe" extension with ShellExecute

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to open an executable file that have no ".exe" extension with ShellExecute. I can use CreateProcess but I prefer to use ShellExecute. There is any way to do it?

I use C++ with the win32api functions.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried ShellExecute with the file to execute that has not ".exe" extension? As far as the OS is concerned, any file that can be executed MUST be formated according to the Portable Executable Specification. As far as this format is concerned, the extension has NO meaning whatsoever!

Comment: I am not familiar with `ShellExecute` but in a quick look at the documentation I found the error code `SE_ERR_NOASSOC` returned when there is no default program associated with the file extension given. This suggests to me that `ShellExecute`'s purpose is to open a given file with the default associated program, a much different purpose than to simply execute a given executable. If this is the case, it seems you are using the wrong tool for the job. Maybe someone else can clarify if I am incorrect, however.

Comment: Have you tried it with CreateProcess? It must be working!

Comment: Thank you, Anthony and mox. I Think that I will use CreateProcess instead.

Comment: As a matter of fact, ShellExecute is tied with the registry and the mapping between the extension and the "verb" to execute...

Comment: CreateProcess works defenitively the way you want it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You use [the `lpClass` member of the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/01/10033224.aspx) to say, "I want you to treat this file as if it were an EXE, even though it doesn't look like one from the extension."

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = {0};
  sei.cbSize = sizeof(sei);
  sei.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  sei.lpFile = TEXT("myprogram.wrongextension");
  sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
  sei.lpVerb = TEXT("open");
  sei.lpClass = TEXT("exefile");
  ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
  return 0;
}
```