# Is there a way to execute an exe stored with a temp file name?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a native exe stored as an embedded resource to the file returned by [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename). That function is desirable since it lets me ignore the implementation details that avoid the race condition. The only downside is that it returns a filename with the extension `.tmp`.

`Process.Start` opens the tmp-named-exe file in Notepad, on my system. Apparently you can specify the class and verb manually using p/invoke (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681219/521757). Before I do that, is there any way to accomplish the same thing using the .NET framework?

Comment: rename the .tmp into .exe before passing it to `Process.Start()`; there is no naming conflict since the file name without extension has been randomized.

Comment: Or just cat .exe on the end for .tmp.exe

Comment: It's theoretically possible for another process to land on the same name that way because the exe file wasn't created as part of the GetTempFileName process. Plus then I have to deleted the created `tmp` file. Either way, I'm still curious about forcing the class/verb.

Comment: what was wrong in my answer? I have wrote the same answer as @MarcWittmann before him getting 0 score. Very curious

Comment: @faby Wasn't wrong, therefore no downvote. I saw both at once. I tend to favour capitalization, punctuation and explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is possible.. set the Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute property to False prior to starting the process, e.g.:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\tmp\a123.tmp";
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute  = false;
 p.Start();
```

This will start the process directly and the file should be considered to be executable itself. Does it work for you?

Comment: I didn't realize UseShellExecute was true by default. Thank you for actually answering the question!

Comment: it's strange that I have wrote the same answer before you but you get 2 of score plus accepted answer

Comment: yes, almost the exact same answer. If that helps I started typing when you did it only took me a few seconds more time, sorry :)

Comment: It throws an error : {"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."}

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [`Path.GetRandomFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in conjunction with [`Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?
This way you still have a unique temporary file and path name and you can append '.exe', eliminating the current problem that you have with executing a file with a '.tmp' extension.

As a sideline, I hope that you remember to delete the temporary files after you have used them, especially when using [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), since it can cause issues when you reach 65535 temporary files. Which is very possible and frustrating to debug when that actually happens on production code.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = //your filename .tmp
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute  = false;
proc.Start();
```