# Open an executable file without an “.exe” extension with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I want to create a process whose filename doesn’t have the `.exe` extension. This is the same question as [Open an executable file without an “.exe” extension with ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655314) had, only with `CreateProcess`. The answer to his question said to set the `sei.lpClass = TEXT("exefile");`. No such parameter in the `STARTUPINFO` structure.

Is there an equivalent solution for `CreateProcess`. Currently, it fails with no extension. Doesn’t even give a proper error message. Just crashes the program.

## Edit2:

Sorry, here's a complete test program demonstrating my problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

LPCTSTR FILE_PATH_NAME = _tcsdup( TEXT( "C:\\File1.exe" ) ); // ok, launches new process correctly
//LPCTSTR FILE_PATH_NAME = _tcsdup( TEXT( "C:\\File1" ) ); // debug assertion in mfc
LPCTSTR FILE_PATH_NAME = _tcsdup( TEXT( "C:\\File1." ) ); // ok, launches new process correctly. Needs ending period (.) to work
LPTSTR commandLine = _tcsdup( TEXT( "1234" ) );

int main()
{
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  STARTUPINFO si;

  ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof( pi ) );
  ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof( si ) );
  si.cb = sizeof( si );

  CreateProcess
  (
    FILE_PATH_NAME,          // must be fully qualified file path name
    commandLine,            // Command line (cannot be const or literal str)
    NULL,                 // Process handle is not inheritable
    NULL,                 // Thread handle is not inheritable
    FALSE,                // handle inheritance false
    0,                    // default
    NULL,                 // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,                 // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,                  // Pointer to startupinfo structure
    &pi                   // Pointer to process_information structure
  );

  DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
  if( lastError != ERROR_SUCCESS )
  {
    // failed
  }

  CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
  CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );

  return 0;
}
```

## Edit3:

Crash image

[image: CreateProcess crash in VS debugger]

Comment: Could you post the code? I think that some arguments were not passed correctly to `CreateProcess`.

Comment: for `CreateProcess` if you use name as first argument - `lpApplicationName` - no matter which extension - only internal file context. so i assume you use name in second argument - `lpCommandLine` - where really result can be depend from file extension. solution - always use not empty `lpApplicationName` - and all will be work for any file name

Comment: @CristiFati I posted the code. The call works fine. Just not without the `.exe` extension.

Comment: @rtischer8277 - but you not show main - `filePathName` and `commandCh` - anyway `CreateProcess` work without any problems for any file extension when `filePathName` used and not 0

Comment: Worked smoothly for me with `filePathName` pointing to the (full) path of the executable (called it _a.out_) and `commandCh` set to `NULL`. Note: test for `GetLastError` only if `CreateProcess` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Using `lpApplicationName` is not required for this. `CreateProcess` slices out the application path from `lpCommandLine`, based on white space or quoting, and passes this to `SearchPath` with an optional ".exe" extension. What exactly are the types and contents of `filePathName` and `commandCh`, and do you have `UNICODE` defined?

Comment: Your error handling is wrong, but despite that your code as posted works perfectly well for me on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.  Are you sure the problem isn't in the executable you're launching?

Comment: @Harry Johnston Glad to hear the sample code is working for you. My test file was a simple generated MFC Dialog program with nothing changed but the caption so the problem is not the .exe file. I'll put the code on some of my other machines to see if it works there. 8 my 10 PCs are running Windows 10 and the other two 8.1.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I have now tested on two other machines with exactly the same problem. I thought it might be a bitness problem, so I did the tests again making sure all compilations were all x86, with no difference in the results. Let’s compare compilers and OS versions. For the 3 tests PCs I am running  VS2017 Version 5.2(26430.14), VS2017 Version 5.2(26403.7) and VS2017 Version 5.2(26430.16). The OSs are 10.0.15063, 10.0.15063 and 10.0.16251 (insider edition).

Comment: Does it work if you also pass `commandLine` as `"C:\\File1"`?  Can you run `C:\File1` in CMD? It calls `CreateProcess` with the fully-qualified path in `lpApplicationName`. If that works, then there's probably something wrong with your build. You say it crashes, so execute it with an attached debugger or configure a post-mortem debugger. That beats guessing.

Comment: @eryksun I am executing the program in the VS debugger. Passing `“C:\\File1”` as `commandLine` with `NULL` in `lpApplicationName` crashes as well. Running from a command prompt gets this: “'File1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file”. See crash images above.

Comment: CMD can execute a file without an extension if you add "." to `PATHEXT`, e.g. `set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.` should make it work.

Comment: I suppose it will fail from CMD too, since it looks like it's the target MFC app itself that's crashing with a failed assertion in mfc140ud.dll.

Comment: Try a child program without MFC, one that just calls MessageBox.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if you've discovered a bug in MFC.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Works fine with an ordinary `C:\\ConsoleApp` as file. Then I looked up the file named in the `Debug Assertion Failed!` dialog at `… atlmfc\src\mfc\appinit.cpp Line: 84`. Here is the line: ` ASSERT(*lpszExt == '.');` Running `C:\\File1.` of course works fine. Next, I checked the docs again to see if I missed it. It was there: “If the file name ends in a period (.) with no extension, or if the file name contains a path, .exe is not appended”. And, of course, the MFC `File1.` program runs fine with an ending period. So, no bug in MFC this time. Sorry, I should have seen that.

Comment: The docs are in error. [`SearchPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527) is called whenever `lpApplicationName` is `NULL`, even if `lpCommandLine` contains a fully-qualified path for the executable. The search includes the optional extension ".exe". Thus "if the file name contains a path", it actually does try appending ".exe". The docs are correct that appending ".exe" isn't tried if the name ends with ".". Anyway, the assert in the MFC code is a bug; it's wrong to require an extension.

Comment: @eryksun Question: how are you able to determine that `SearchPath` is called whenever `lpApplicationName` is `NULL`? Are you reading this in the docs somewhere? Are you able to debug into `CreateProcess`?

Comment: It's from debugging `kernelbase!CreateProcessInternalW` with several test cases. There's a lot of work to do in user mode before calling `ntdll!NtCreateUserProcess`, so a lot of the behavior can be discerned with a user-mode debugger. The kernel side is more tedious because you're limited in what you can do with live kernel debugging, such as not being able to set breakpoints. Kernel debugging generally requires two computers, or at least a VM.

Comment: @eryksun In the past I have sometimes been able to modify MFC directly in usermode by overriding the MFC function in my app code. In this case the function is `void CWinApp::SetCurrentHandles()` in the `…\atlmfc\src\mfc\appinit.cpp` file. I tried this as an experiment, but was unable to `break` in the new code. My theory was that `void MyWinApp::SetCurrentHandles()` would override it and in my code I would eliminate the `ASSERT` on `’.’`. Shouldn’t it be possible to do this and stay in usermode debugging? It would be a big advantage for us app developers.